GCP: Serverless VPC Connector not working with Cloud Functions
I have the following network setup:
[GCP VPC]* -> [Cloud VPN Gateway & Tunnel (IPSec IKEv2)] -> [on premises]**
*internal IP range: 10.0.0.0/24
**internal IP range: 10.106.0.0/20
On premises, I have an API (Node.js) running on 10.106.0.2:3000.
I want to make HTTP calls to the aforementioned API from GCP.
(All traffic besides the IPSec tunnel from GCP is blocked)
A) From a VM (this works)
If I run a VM attached to GCP's VPC that's "connected" to the on-premises network, I am able to:
ping 10.106.0.2       # OK
curl 10.106.0.2:3000  # OK

The following Node.js script works perfectly:
# script.js

async function run() {
    const url = 'http://10.106.0.2:3000';

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.text();
        console.log('Response:', data);
        res.status(200).send(data); // Returns the expected response from the API
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error.message);
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
}

run();

# Reaches the on-premises API and returns the expected response
$ node script.js

B) From a Cloud Function (this doesn't work)
I configured a Serverless VPC Connector.
Then I created a Cloud Function (gen1) with access to the Connector (tried both "Private ranges only" and "All traffic" as egress routing settings).
The function does the same as the script in the VM:
exports.helloWorld = async (req, res) => {
    const url = 'http://10.106.0.2:3000';

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.text();
        console.log('Response:', data);
        res.status(200).send(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error.message);
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
};

This doesn't work. I get the following error from the function:
{"cause":{"name":"ConnectTimeoutError","code":"UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT","message":"Connect Timeout Error"}}

Additionally, I tried setting extra firewall rules as described here for all TCP ingress traffic (and port 3000 specifically as well). This didn't help.
Any ideas? Am I missing something?
Edit:
I've created a "Connectivity Test" to check the connection between my Cloud Function and 10.106.0.2:3000:

Edit 2:
For comparison, this is how the "Connectivity Test" from the VM to the same target (10.106.0.2:3000) looks like:


add the static route mentioned in the doc inside the VM instead of in the GCP Routes page.

Not sure I follow, @SaiChandraGadde. Could you please elaborate? Thanks!

By default, the VPC Connector egress_setting of private-ranges-only will only route requests to RFC 1918 and RFC 6598 IP address ranges or internal DNS names to your VPC network.

All connector instances get the network tag "vpc-connector" and a specific tag in the format "aet-REGION-CONNECTOR_NAME". Some projects have a VPC network firewall rule to deny egress traffic which can block egress from the VPC Connector, but only when the VPC Connector is routing all traffic through the connector by setting the egress_setting to all-traffic.

If this is the case, to allow egress traffic specifically from a connector, which is using the all-traffic egress_setting, create an egress allow firewall rule with the relevant tags

You can also use Connectivity test wherein you can place the source and the destination of the traffic and monitor where the packet will drop.

I already have a Firewall rule that allows egress for (all) vpc-connector(s). The egress setting for the CF is also set to "all traffic" already.

But the connectivity tests tool you mentioned is very helpful, thanks. I'll see if I can pinpoint the issue with it.

So initially there was no connectivity between 10.1.0.1 (IP in VPC Connector's range) and 10.106.0.2 (target IP). That was because I had to re-create the VPN Tunnel (policy-based) to add the Connector's IP Range (10.1.0.0/28) to the list of local IP Ranges. When I first created the VPN Tunnel the VPC Connector did not exist yet, hence its range was missing. Problem solved, I thought... but the Cloud Function still throws the exact same error :D

can you add details on how you have configuring cloud functions with VPC, attach any documents you are following.

[Console]: Cloud Function -> Connections -> Egress Settings -> Network: select the right Connector from dropdown -> Check "route all traffic through the VPC connector". Done.
The connectivity test (see edit in original question), shows that everything should be ok.

Are you following this Document for creating Serverless VPC Access connector and Configure your function to connect to a VPC network. If not, can you share the Document you are following? Also share which runtime you are using to create the cloud function and the code?

Yes, that one. As already mentioned, it's a 1st-gen Node.js Cloud Function. The code is also part of the question above.

I tried to deploy the code you shared in cloud functions by creating a Serverless VPC Access connector by following the Document and successfully deployed without any errors. Can you make sure your app is listening on port 3000.

Does this help

I've also deployed it successfully without any errors. The question is, does the request from the CF to on-prem go through?

To solve this issue, I had to edit the IPSec configuration on my on-premises server (/etc/ipsec.conf).
The internal IP range of the Serverless VPC Connector (10.1.0.0/28 in my case) had to be added to rightsubnet:
config setup
    protostack=netkey

conn mysubnet
     also=mytunnel
     leftsubnet=10.106.0.0/20
     rightsubnet=10.0.0.0/24,10.1.0.0/28 # <--- HERE
     auto=start

conn mytunnel
    left=x.x.x.x # the external IP of the on-premises server
    right=y.y.y.y # the external IP of GCP's Cloud VPN Gateway
    authby=secret

Now everything works properly:
a) requests from any VM (in 10.0.0.0/24) and
b) requests from any Cloud Function with a Serverless VPC Connector (in 10.1.0.0/28) attached to it.
